# Executing tftp command without entering tftp command line

Tags: command-line, bash, tftp

I want to execute the `tftp` command without entering into the "`tftp` command line".

I have tried the below commands:

```bsh
tftp xx.xx.xx.xx -c put file1 file2
tftp xx.xx.xx.xx -m binary -c file1 file2
```

But I got:

```
usage:tftp host-name [port]
tftp>
```

After the "usage:" message its entering the `tftp` command line.

I have tried it with the verbose option turned on.

I just want to know if the command I given worked properly. The "usage:" message makes it seem like it's not the correct usage of the `tftp` command.

This command is to be invoked from a Bash file which will be invoked from a CLI application I am working on.

I have followed the advices on this link : https://superuser.com/questions/581812/put-file-with-tftp-client-in-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use heredoc (`<<`) to enter the commands to execute one after another:

```
tftp host <<'EOF'
Enter
Commands
Here
EOF
```

**Example:**

```
$ tftp localhost <<'EOF'
> ascii
> status
> quit
> EOF

tftp> tftp> Connected to localhost.
Mode: netascii Verbose: off Tracing: off
Rexmt-interval: 5 seconds, Max-timeout: 25 seconds
tftp> 

$
```

---

If you desired `tftp` command is

```
get file1 /home/foobar/test.txt
```

you can do:

```
$ tftp host <<'EOF'
> get file1 /home/foobar/test.txt
> quit
> EOF
```

Comment: I tried it as    
    "**tftp -c get file1 /home/test.txt << quit**"

but no activity noted here. no test.txt file created at home

Comment: @runner at first just enter `tftp host <<'EOF'` at first, then press enter and move on to the next ones..check my edits

Comment: Actually I want to invoke this from an another cli. so this entire command will be in another bash file. I executed with the commands you gave me. but its still entering **tftp** command line

Comment: can you suggest how can i provide these commands in a bash file in order to avoid entering tftp command line

Comment: @runner The commands go line by line in the script..just do it like my first snippet..